# Entity framework DbEntityValidationException- could not find the entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to post the data from my register form to my database.At first i had a very common error "the entity type `<model>` is not part of the model for the current context". I solve it and then another error appeared. So now the error that appeared was in the SaveChanges section and it is "could not found the entity Password". How can I fix that?

**Here is the code of my context.**

```
public partial class MyDbEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyDbEntities()
        : base("name=MyDbEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Surname).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Email).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.password).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.address).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.postcode).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.number).IsRequired();

    }
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            string errorMessages = string.Join("; ", ex.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
            throw new DbEntityValidationException(errorMessages);
        }
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

**And here is the code of my controller**

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(User U)
    {
        using(MyDbEntities db=new MyDbEntities())
        {
            db.Users.Add(U);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();
            U = null;
            ViewBag.Message("Seccesfully stored");
        }
        return View(U);
    }
```

**And the model**
`

```
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Surname")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType (DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string password { get; set; }


        [Required]
       [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        public string address { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "PostVode")]
        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        public string postcode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        public string number { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please post the precise error

Comment: well that's not very easy because the error is written in greek but i will translate. It says it is not possible to find the entity with the name "password".

Comment: hahaha.  Ok then.  Well the only thing that I can think of is that you have a `[Required]` attribute on the `password` property, and you haven't set it, or it isn't set on the `User U` parameter that you're passing to your method.

Comment: i double checked that and i don't think that's the problem. Also another wierd thing happened. i comment the password just to see if that's the problem an the  "The entity type User is not part of the model for the current context." appeared again...

Comment: I'll post an answer that shows how my DbContext is set up.... let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that `User` is part of your DbContext.  This is how I have mine set up:

```
public partial class MyDbEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyDbEntities()
        : base("name=MyDbEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Add the mapping class in here, instead of the setup
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            string errorMessages = string.Join("; ", ex.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
            throw new DbEntityValidationException(errorMessages);
        }
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

The user mapping class, note that it inherits from `EntityTypeConfiguration<User>`, I think that this is the bit you're missing:

```
public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        // Your original setup goes here
        this.ToTable("Users");
        this.Property(u => u.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
        this.Property(u => u.Surname).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
        this.Property(u => u.Email).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);
        this.Property(u => u.password).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        this.Property(u => u.address).IsRequired();
        this.Property(u => u.postcode).IsRequired();
        this.Property(u => u.number).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Either that, or maybe it's this that you're missing.  My DbContext has a static constructor that sets the Database Initializer, if yours doesn't have it already, try adding it:

```
static MyDbEntities()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<MyDbEntities>(null);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately no luck at all.... Let me see if i got it right... i went to my dbcontext and added your code. I created a new class the UserMap as you did... but it still gives me this error :(
Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: Oh that's a shame then :(.  I'm not sure what could cause it

Comment: now i did some changes in my controller's method and i have another error which is maybe an improvement since it's not the same error hahaha.the error says Unable to update the EntitySet 'Users' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation. any ideas?